# Injecting PHP URL variable into HTML

Tags: php, html

Trying to inject HTML into PHP code to allow the creation of dynamic sharing links on my site.

I have attempted the code below, but it's resulting in an error

```
<?php 
// Program to display URL of current page. 

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') 
    $link = "https"; 
else
    $link = "http"; 

// Here append the common URL characters. 
$link .= "://"; 

// Append the host(domain name, ip) to the URL. 
$link .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 

// Append the requested resource location to the URL 
$link .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
?> 


<center><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?


<?php echo $link; ?>

">Facebook</center>
```

I am getting an error on line 20 saying FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file on line number 20

Comment: Whats on line 20? What error?

Comment: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file on line number 20

Answer (score 0):

seems code is not formatted correctly or you have

```
<center>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?<?php echo $link; ?>">Facebook</a>

</center>
```